# Errors in AutoDock

Tags: docking

I am using Autodock and I'm getting an error in the step where we get the glg file (i.e. Run--> Autogrid) I am not sure what should I do...Please help me if someone knows how to tackle this. Plus yep there's no space in the folder file name and I have all exe and dat files in the same one folder.

```
                         $Revision: 1.109 $

Compilation parameters:  NUM_RECEPTOR_TYPES=20 NEINT=2048

MAX_MAPS=16 NDIEL=16384 MAX_ATOM_TYPES=14

energy_lookup table has   655360 entries of size 8

e_vdW_Hb table has   401408 entries of size 8

Maximum number of maps that can be computed = 16 (defined by MAXMAPS in "autocomm.h").

GPF> npts 18 12 24                        # num.grid points in xyz

Number of grid points in x-direction:    19

Number of grid points in y-direction:    13

Number of grid points in z-direction:    25

GPF> gridfld 98 Alanine_over_Phenylalanine.maps.fld # grid_data_file

C:/Bioinformatics/Docking/autogrid4.exe: ERROR:  Grid data file needs the extension ".fld" for AVS input

C:/Bioinformatics/Docking/autogrid4.exe: Unsuccessful Completion.
```

[image: my gpf file which I used to generate further glg step, do you think there's something wrong in it?]

Comment: Welcome to the site @Khanishka. One thing thats not clear is whether the installation is successful. Have you successfully run test data?

Comment: @M__  Yes installation is successful. As far as I know yes I have